# Changed front brake pads on 06 GMC Z71, then the master cylinder and brake booster failed

Tags: brakes, gmc

I put new brake pads on the front of my 06 GMC Z71. After finishing, I noticed I didn't have any brakes. The peddle was spongy so I bled the brakes. And bled the brakes, and bled the brakes. I could never get the pedal to feel like it's supposed to. Took it to a mechanic and  he bled the brakes. It still didn't fix the problem. After a major debacle of getting the wrong parts, the mechanic changed the master cylinder. The problem still wasn't fixed because the brake pedal wouldn't push down.  So he then had to change the brake booster. When he took it off air "exploded" out of  it. My question, is this normal? Why did changing my pads cause me to have $730.00 worth of repairs? I never once had any problems before. I had changed my pads  because they had started "squealing." I bought the truck used with 80,000 miles on it, in very good condition. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Sierra, Yukon, or Yukon XL? Assuming not a Denali as I don't believe they came in Z71 trim. More than likely this is just coincidence. Depending on how the brakes were bled (manually I assume?), it could just be everything just happened. I've got 155k+ on my 06 Silvy Z71 and don't have any issues with the brakes. Also, does this have hydroboost or a normal vacuum booster (assume vacuum, but have to ask)?

Comment: When you put the new pads in, did the process involve opening the hydraulic system in any way before you realized you had no brakes?

Comment: How did you push the pistons back to make space for the new pads?

Comment: Also realize that if you bleed the brakes by pumping the pedal and you mash it all the way to the floor, it will often push the piston cup further into the master cylinder than it usually goes and collapse the rubber piston cup or get crud stuck under the lip, preventing pressure from building.

You should NEVER have pressure in the brake booster vacuum lines. Ever. So if you did, it indicates that either something was done incorrectly or maybe you just heard air rushing *in*? It should always hold a little bit of vacuum.